# Scraping "hidden" table from webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the table at this URL: https://www.agenas.gov.it/covid19/web/index.php?r=site%2Ftab2 .
I tried reading it qith requests and BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
s = requests.session()
req = s.get('https://www.agenas.gov.it/covid19/web/index.php?r=site%2Ftab2', headers={
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
               "Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"})
soup = bs(req.content)
table = soup.find('table')
```

However, I only get the headers of the table.

```
<table class="table">
<caption class="pl8">Ricoverati e posti letto in area non critica e terapia intensiva.</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="cella-tabella-sm align-middle text-center" scope="col">Regioni</th>
<th class="cella-tabella-sm bg-blu align-middle text-center" scope="col">Ricoverati in Area Non Critica</th>
<th class="cella-tabella-sm bg-blu align-middle text-center" scope="col">PL in Area Non Critica</th>
<th class="cella-tabella-sm bg-blu align-middle text-center" scope="col">Ricoverati in Terapia intensiva</th>
<th class="cella-tabella-sm bg-blu align-middle text-center" scope="col">PL in Terapia Intensiva</th>
<th class="cella-tabella-sm bg-blu align-middle text-center" scope="col">PL Terapia Intensiva attivabili</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tab2_body">
</tbody>
</table>
```

So I tried with the URL i *think* the table is located: https://Agenas:tab2-19@www.agenas.gov.it/covid19/web/index.php?r=json%2Ftab2 .
But in this case I always get 401 status code, even adding in headers username and password as shown in previous request. For example:

```
 requests.get('https://Agenas:tab2-19@www.agenas.gov.it/covid19/web/index.php?r=json%2Ftab2', headers={'username':'Agenas', 'password':'tab2-19'
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'})
```

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: If the data in the table is dynamically loaded with javascript you might have to use selenium.

Comment: @Jortega just FYI, this can be done *without* the heavy guns of `selenium`.

Comment: @Panzerotto remember to mark the answer that solves your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "secrets" needed for the `headers` are actually embedded in a `<script>` tag. So you can fish them out, parse'em to a `JSON` and use in the `request headers`.

Here's how:

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    end_point = "https://Agenas:tab2-19@www.agenas.gov.it/covid19/web/index.php?r=json%2Ftab2"
    regular_page = "https://www.agenas.gov.it/covid19/web/index.php?r=site%2Ftab2"

    html = s.get(regular_page, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all("script")[-1].string

    hacked_payload = json.loads(
        re.search(r"headers:\s({.*}),", soup, re.S).group(1).strip()
    )

    headers.update(hacked_payload)
    print(json.dumps(s.get(end_point, headers=headers).json(), indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "regione": "Abruzzo",
    "dato1": "667",
    "dato2": "1495",
    "dato3": "89",
    "dato4": "215",
    "dato5": "0"
  },
  {
    "regione": "Basilicata",
    "dato1": "164",
    "dato2": "426",
    "dato3": "12",
    "dato4": "88",
    "dato5": "13"
  },

and so on ...
```